# How to apply to hide TinyMCE (wp_editor) on button click

Tags: plugins, javascript, tinymce

I'm not whether this question is a duplicate, and I'm sorry if it is.

I have this plugin that works on the admin side. There, I have a page on which I need to print at least one TinyMCE editor. After reading the codex, I figured out that I could print one to the front-end using wp_editor.

```
<?php wp_editor("Some text", "my-editor");?>
```

However, I need to make some changes to this editor on certain events. For instance, there's a case where the editor should be hidden on a button click; I also need to get texts from and into the editor's text area in certain situations, this should be done dynamically via JS/JQuery.

I thought that it would be possible to do all those things by just selecting the editor id (my-editor) just like any other element. Things didn't turn out the way I expect. I've tested some JQuery, here's how it might look like:

```
$("#btn-hide-editor").click(function() {
    $("#my-editor").css("display", "none");
});
```

For this specific case of making the display property equal none, I've also tried to wrap the editor with a div and, then, make that div "display: none". It doesn't work either.

I would be grateful if anyone could point out what I'm missing here and what might be a solution.

EDIT 1:

This "issue" only occurs when on the Visual tab of the editor. My code seems to work for the Text tab. Ideally, I wish to be a be able to use the Visual tab, so this is still an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok you need to remove the wrap div of editor like :

```
$("#btn-hide-editor").click(function() {
    $("#wp-my-editor-wrap").css("display", "none");
});
```

wrap div id Consists of **wp-[your-id]-wrap**

Comment: Hey, it worked! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, man!

Comment: Sabry, I also need to change the text inside the Visual editor on button click. Is there a way similar to your solution to make this? I tried `jQuery('#wp-my-editor-wrap').val(example_value);` but it didn't word. Should I be using another id?

Comment: This way you can change the content within the editor :
tinymce.get("my-editor").setContent("<p>Hello world!</p>");

Comment: It worked again, that's awesome. Thank you once more :)